# How can I integrate regex into my MapHttpRoute for WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I currently have:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "AccountApiCtrl",
                routeTemplate: "/api" + "/account/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "accountapi", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Which sends **/api/account/myaction requests to accountapi controller**. (it works great :-))

However, I'd rather not do this for each controller I have, is there a way I can use regex here so that I only have on declaration?

I.E so:

**/api/account/action goes to controller: AccountApi
and
/api/user/action goes to controller: UserApi**

i.e something along the lines of:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ControllerApiMap",
                routeTemplate: "/api" + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "{controller}+api", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is one way of achieving this:

```
    config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new CustomHttpControllerSelector(config));

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

---

```
public class CustomHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    public CustomHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config)
        : base(config)
    {
    }

    public override string GetControllerName(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        IHttpRouteData routeData = request.GetRouteData();

        if (routeData.Values.ContainsKey("controller"))
        {
            return routeData.Values["controller"] + "api";
        }

        return base.GetControllerName(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, change as per below where you will be change regex:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // Route Pattern
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Default values for parameters
   new { controller = "^H.*", action = "^Index$|^Contact$" } //Restriction for controller and action
);
```

Here, controller name start with H like Home and action start with Index or Contact, other's are ristricted.